# cleanup / organise the /config/initializers folder for new rails 4 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Migrating from a rails 3 project and found that I have to many initialisers for my taste, 
trying to clean out the config folder and minimise the use of initialisers or better organise them.

Currently I have:

```
...
-rw-r--r--   1 Me  staff     81 Jun 22 14:54 simple_navigation.rb
-rw-r--r--   1 Me  staff   1535 Jun 22 14:54 simple_navigation_overrule.rb
-rw-r--r--   1 Me  staff     27 Jun 22 14:54 will_paginate.rb
-rw-r--r--   1 Me  staff    514 Sep 10 23:12 wrap_parameters.rb
```

Are there ways to clean this up a bit or use subfolders to organise this better? I feel there are several initialisers im not sure still needed like the fix_ssl.rb one and some other initialisers that only have a 1 line.

Preferrable I would like to clean this up more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can create whatever subdirectories you need.

From the guide for [using initializer files](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files):

> You can use subfolders to organize your initializers if you like,
>   because Rails will look into the whole file hierarchy from the
>   initializers folder on down.